# how to add a style-tag to angular 5 app body

Tags: css, angular, angular5

We have a services that aggregates a lot of information which I want to display in an angular 5 app.
The model to display this is constantly changing and shared accros a lot of apps so I want to import it dynamically.

My idea was to query that model in a service, hand it to the components which need it, and they just print it out as css-rules.

The generation of css rules in the component works fine and I get a variable which holds the string containing all the rules:

```
this.css
```

in my html-code I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<style>
  {{css}}
</style>
```

Sadly the style-tags are removed no matter what I do.

Why are they removed? What can I do to make this work?
Is there another way, like handing the style to angular to add them to the header?

Comment: where are you adding `<style>` tags in your HTML?

Comment: the first thing in the *.component.html

Comment: what you are actually trying to do can you elaborate?

Comment: I have a string containing css and I want to add that to the body (or head if possible)

Comment: see my below answer with the demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to the Component HTML by sanitizing the `<style>`.

Angular provides [**`DomSanitizer`**](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) service which is inside the `@angular/platform-browser` package

You should be doing as below,

HTML Code should be as

```
 <div [innerHTML]="getStyles()"></div>
```

Typescript Method should be as

```
getStyles(){
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.styles);
}
```

Note: In my code the value of

```
styles = `<style>
                body {background-color: red;}
                h1   {color: blue;}
                p    {color: red;}
          </style>`
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/hxeFPoQQH5DwZGi3FSOp?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, For some reason the domSanitizer doesn't allow css.

Comment: @NDDT so did you get a chance to look into the demo

Comment: I think Aravind meant `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` not `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`?

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a native js-function to create a new stylesheet and added my rules to that.